# Zookeeper ACL based on host throws error

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I want to create ACL in Zookeeper which is based on host, here's what I'm trying to do.

In zkCli -

`>>> setAcl / host:example.com:crdw`

But I get this error.

`Acl is not valid : /`

I can set ACL based on IP just fine, so `>>> setAcl / ip:10.10.10.10:crdw` 
works.

What am I doing wrong with the host based ACL?